# Handlebars doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Please help me to learn Handlebars. I'm trying for first time and I don't know why this code isn't work. The first part of code is in my html.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
            <script id="contact-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>
                <div class="entry">
                        <h1>I'm {{title}}</h1>
                        <div class="body">
                          {{body}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
            </script>


  (async function (){ 
      let source = $('#contact-template')
      let template = Handlebars.compile(source);

      let context = {
        title: "My New Post",
        body: "This is my first post!"
      };
      let html = template(context);
      $('#container').append(html);
 }())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwM9v.png)

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: no, there is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the handlebars package first in [handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html)

lets try this.. hope this can help you and don't forget to add the package into your project and call the package

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v4.0.11.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        let entry = '<div id="contact-template">' +
                    '<div class="entry">' +
                      '<h1>I`m {{title}}</h1>' +
                      '<div class="body">{{body}}</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                  '</div>'
        let source = entry;
        let template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        let context = {
          title: "My New Post",
          body: "This is my first post!"
        };
        let html = template(context);
        $('#container').append(html);
      </script>
</body>
```

NB: Don't use `<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">` because the script is not running when the page loading, but use `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: I did it, but doesn't work. I added a picture to my code.

Comment: have you add the package? look at my head tag

Comment: yes I have '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v4.0.11.js"></script>', if I delete it I have error: ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined

Comment: now works but duplicates it. First I have 
I'm {{title}}
{{body}} and after that I have  
I'm My New Post
This is my first post!

Comment: I have changed it.. let see one more time

Comment: Thank you very much